# Can I explore London by Roller skating?

Tags: legal, transportation, london, outdoor-activities, england

I'm French and I plan to stroll in London for a few days.

I usually enjoy sightseeing alone, on my roller skates. In France it's mostly allowed to skate on sidewalks, you may even sneak between the cars (if you are agile enough, cops usually don't mind/notice). What about London?

Comment: Well motorists find motorcyclists and cyclists annoying, motorcyclists and cyclists find motorists annoying, and cyclists and skaters can find each other annoying too. And of course all of these can greatly annoy pedestrians too, so it pretty much goes without saying.

Comment: This is a good question. In Australia I've been pulled over by the police for rollerblading on the road in three states, but the police always ignore me in Sydney. So both the legality and the enforcement definitely varies from place to place. You may have to use bicycle lanes when available but on one famous bridge I have been told specifically to the bike side and not the pedestrian side, and on another occasion was told the exact opposite! I found rollerblading accepted as a legitimate form of city transport in Canada and Western Europe though.

Comment: @yota There is alot of roller skating & blading in London parks particularly Hyde Park & The Serpentine, I think the craze to do this on sidewalks etc has died down in recent years. Motorists might find you annoying, but when you are stuck in Central London traffic all day long, anything will annoy.

Comment: You'll likely end up with wet feet if you try roller skating in The Serpentine

Comment: @Peregrine Looks like Diego agrees with about Hyde Park & The Serpentine

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Absolutely! And not only you can, it is one of the best ways to explore the City! My favourite place to start the journey is from Hyde Park - right by the Serpentine Lake is a nice place to eat a sandwich and start skating, while you see some people dancing on rollers and quads.

There are also some places to rent inlines in case you can't take yours with you near Hyde Park ([Slick Willies](http://www.slickwillies.co.uk/skate-hire/) and [Club Blueroom](http://www.clubblueroom.com/Rentals.asp) come to my mind). They usually provide skate pads as well.

You may want to attend the [LFNS](http://www.lfns.co.uk/) (London Friday Night Skate) weekly meetings -on Fridays and Sundays-, which are very well organised and safe, as they always have marshals holding the traffic while the rest of the people just enjoy the ride. It is run by volunteers, and the people is just great. I can't recommend these rides enough.

If you want to go solo, you can either go by road or on the sidewalks (but please be careful if you do so). The police officers will not disturb you unless they find that you are annoying the rest of the pedestrians.

By the way, keep looking the road ahead of you, as London roads are far from perfect and there may be holes in the ground or even rubber cables crossing the road side to side.

Some other *must-skate* places in London are Greenwich park, Kensington and Chelsea boroughs and Oxford St./Regent St. (these one on Sunday mornings, as they are a bit too crowded otherwise).

Comment: Much approved answer, tour included :) I'm looking forward to try the LFNS. I was marshal on the Bordeaux (France) Friday Night Skate (I do recommend it ;) I'll write about french regulation in another post, if someone is interested?